# Factor Theorem (Finding values of a and b)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factoring

> > Question: The polynomial $p(x) = 2x^3 - ax^2 + bx + 48$ has $(x-4)$ as a repeated factor, find the values of $a$ and $b$.

---

What I have attempted

if $x-4$ is a factor then $x = 4$ is a root

then $$ p(4) = 2(4)^3 -a(4)^2 + b(4) + 48 = 0 $$

then $$ -16a + 4b = -176 $$

then I have 2 equations which are the same thing so I cannot find a and b?

My teacher said I could find the derivative of $p(x)$ and then plug in $x=4$ but why does that work? I'm confused..

Comment: If (x-4) is a repeated factor.  Then taking the derivative of $p(x)$ will still have (x-4) as a factor.  Hence the derivative evaluated at $0$ will be equal to zero.

Comment: @mathamphetamines but why does that work , why does the gradient function equal to zero when it is a root?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The OP asked *why* a repeated root is a factor of the derivative. Let $p$ be a polynomial with root $r$. By the factor theorem $(x-r)^2 \mid p$ so there is some polynomial $q$ with $p = q (x-r)$ and $x-r \mid q$. Then
$$\frac{dp}{dx} = \frac{d}{dx} q (x-r) = (x-r)\frac{dq}{dx} + q\frac{d}{dx} (x-r).$$
As $x-r \mid q$, the rightmost expression is clearly divisible by $x-r$.

In fact, we didn't even use that $x-r$ and $p$ are polynomials. If $f$ is *any* function of $x$ and $p$ is *any* function of $x$ divisible by $f^2$ then $f \mid \frac{dp}{dx}$ by the same argument.

Comment: So this only works when there is a repeated factor?

Comment: @dydxx Yes. Otherwise you would end up with $\frac{dp}{dx} = (x-r)\frac{dq}{dx} + q$, where there is no guarantee that $q$ is divisible by $x$. Actually I will rework the above argument to be simpler.

Comment: While $\frac{d}{dx}x - r = \frac{d}{dx}(x - r)$, I would have written $\frac{d}{dx}(x - r)$ to emphasize that you are differentiating the factor $x - r$ when applying the product rule.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Good call. I made that change.

Answer (score 0):

$p'(x) = 6x^2 - 2ax + b$.

Since $(x-4)$ is a repeated factor, we know that $(x-4)$ is a factor of the derivative.  Hence $p'(4)= 0$.

Thus $p'(4) = 96 - 8a + b = 0$.

The rest is just algebra.